# Function of return statement and method parameters in java?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in java. I don't know the function of return statement and method parameters in java. Can you please explain it to me further and when should it be used?

Here's my code:

```
public class Person{

    public  void  display (String name){                     
        System.out.println("hello" + name );
    }


    public int execute (int num1, int num2){
        int result = num1 + num2;
        return result;
    }

    public void display1(int num){
        System.out.println("the number is: " + num);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _return method_? The _return_ statement?

Comment: Is your google broken? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_statement

Comment: sorry.its return statement

Comment: In that case, check out the link posted by @timgeb. This is very basic stuff, and we can't explain the entire structure of Java for you.

Comment: return means you have a result to pass back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Parameters** refers to the list of variables in a method declaration. Arguments are the actual values that are passed in when the method is invoked. When you invoke a method, the arguments used must match the declaration's parameters in type and order.

Example:

```
  double sales_tax(double price)
  {
      return 0.05 * price;
  }
```

After the function has been defined, it can be invoked as follows:

```
  sales_tax(10.00);
```

In this example, the function has been invoked with the number 10.00. When this happens, 10.00 will be assigned to price, and the function begins calculating its result. The steps for producing the result are specified below enclosed in {} "0.05 * price" indicates that the first thing to do is multiply 0.05 by the value of price, which gives 0.50. "return" means the function will produce the result of "0.05 * price". Therefore, the final result is 0.50.

The return statement is used to explicitly return from a method. That is, it causes program control to transfer back to the caller of the method. As such, it is categorized as a jump statement. A brief look at return is presented here.

like for example:

```
 public int execute (int num1, int num2){

    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
 }

  Person prsn = new Person();

  int getSum = prsn.execute(1,1);
```

the value of getSum will be the value of result through which you have returned in the method execute that you have invoked.

Answer (score 1):

According to how i understand you question, the return parameter (datatype according to what i understood) is the data type your method should retrun when called (e.g. void int,string,float). 
The second question which i think you are asking is when to use the return key name in a method. This should be used when you have a method that you want to return results to the calling variable after execution of the method e.g

```
//this is a your class that performs some related task

public class Person{

public  void  display (String name){                     
    System.out.println("hello" + name );
}


public int execute (int num1, int num2){
    int result = num1 + num2;
    return result;
}

public void display1(int num){
    System.out.println("the number is: " + num);
}
}

//main class or the calling class

public class MainCallingClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //instantiate the Person class here
    Person prsn = new Person();

    //calls the execute(),which adds 2 numbers inside Person class 
    int getSum = prsn.execute(1,1); 
    System.out.println("Sum of 1 and 1 is: " + getSum );

}
}
```

Answer (score -5):

From [this page](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/15methodex.html):

> This example shows a simple method that computes the area of a rectangle:

```
public static int computeArea(int width, int height) {
    int area;   // This is a local variable
    area = width * height;
    return area;
}
```

> Line 1: This is the method header. The first int indicates that the value this method returns is going to be an integer. The name of the function is "computeArea", and it has two integer parameters: width and height.
>
> Line 2...4: The body of the method starts with the left brace, "{", on the end of the first line. The "{" doesn't have to be on the same line as the header, but this is a common style.
>      The body of this simple function contains a declaration on line 2, an assignment statement in line 3, and a return statement on line 4. If a method returns a value, then there must be at least one return statement. A void method (one which does not return a value),
>     does not require a return statement, and will automatically return at the end of the method.

Comment: giving knowledge to other is not a bad thing

Comment: it's my pleasure @user3783598

Comment: @HarpreetHarry No, it isn't, but plagiarizing *is* a bad thing.